# Using commas to store friends-relationship in a social networking site

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm working with another developer to develop a sort of social networking site, where people can make Friend Requests similar to that in Facebook. However, he's storing each user's friend as comma-separated values:

```
user_id | user_friends
101     | 102,103,105
```

I'm convinced that this is very inefficient and error-prone. I'd personally use a relational database model and create another table with columns `friendship_id (PRIMARY KEY), friender_id and friended_id.`

Am I right? And what arguments should I give to support my stance? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.

With his system, how will you handle the status of the friendship request (i.e canceled, pending, accepted) ?

Parsing the user_friends string will be a pain and you won't be able to use joins for complex data fetching.

Answer (score 1):

ALthough using comma seperated is OK but difficult to manage for searching you will have to use FIND_IN_SET and on updation you will have to do a little more work. Intead using the other way is easy to use. You can easily add as mush relationships as you like. And searching is of course easy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more reason: Any comparisons between two users friends will be cumbersome with a comma seperated record. What friends to people have in common, for example will have to be handleded outside the database, which means that you will need to fetch all data and then compare. 
Data transfer is one of the major bottlenecks when using databases.

Another reason yet would be that using comma seperated records in a relational database, for something that is so inherently relational is downright stupid. But that reason might be a but less factual...